# Command line sendmail quit working after June 6

Tags: gmail, sendmail

Since June 6 all scripts sending mail to my gmail account have stopped working and Thunderbird is asking repeatedly to enter my password, which has not changed in the last week.
I am running Ubuntu 20.04, 5.13.0-44-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 18 18:44:28 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux. I have turned on 2 step verification and have checked my Google settings at least twice. I have now fixed Thunderbird, using the information here: https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/1369886
I am using sendmail to alert myself of scripts, such as backups, that have run. I have added code to put the logfiles in my logs directory but would still like the alert emails. I used this article to reconfigure exim4, but that did not fix the problem: https://www.talk-about-it.ca/setting-up-exim4-with-gmail-and-2-factor-authentication/

June 10: All of a sudden I have a flood of gmail messages generated by scripts appearing in my inbox. I had just changed the password in exim4.config to the application password! Hooray! Thanks for the help. Generating the application password via Google and plugging that into /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template did the trick. That is in the line starting with client_send, line 1887 approx.
The line is:

client_send = : username@gmail.com : 'userpassword'

Mark as solved.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Have you checked your Google accounts settings? Do you have 2 step authentication turned on?

Comment: See [this news story](https://www.tomsguide.com/news/google-forcing-2fa-users).

Comment: Google has stated that after May 30 2022 ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password. But how do I change exm4 to send mail from the command line??

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1413016/edit) and add all the new information I have asked for.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 20.04,  5.13.0-44-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 18 18:44:28 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux. I have turned on 2 step verification, but I will revisit it after reading that news story. I have checked my Google accounts settings at least twice.

Comment: Edit your question above, rather than adding new information in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has announced that after May 30 it will be impossible to use password-only authentication in any non-web apps accessing the Google account. This means you cannot use your password anymore in neither IMAP nor SMTP.

As for Thunderbird, you have to change your account configuration to use OAuth2 authentication instead of password, it should be pretty simple.

For scripts, it depends on the MTA (mail server) you are using. I guess you are using Exim (there's no such thing as "exm4", but there is "exim4" - you probably meant that) in a configuration that **submits** (not **sends**) mail to your Gmail account - hence the need for authentication.

You have several options.

1. If Exim can be configured to use OAuth2 (I don't know - you have to search the Net for information), you can reconfigure it, as you do with Thunderbird.
2. If Exim doesn't support OAuth2, you can uninstall it and install another MTA that does support OAuth2. I know that Postfix does (although I have never configured it).
3. You can switch your Google account to use 2-factor authentication. Then you will be able to generate an **application password** (it is possible only for accounts with 2FA turned on) for your MTA. Replace your normal password in your MTA configuration with that generated password. It should work as previously.
4. If you are only sending mail from scripts to your Gmail account, maybe you actually don't need **submission** at all. This is required when you want to **relay** mail via Google to other recipients, not when sending to Google as a final destination. You can simply **send** the mail to Gmail like any external host does, to port 25 without any authentication. This of course requires changing configuration of your MTA (you now probably have it configured to use Gmail as "smarthost"; reconfigure it as a standalone site that sends mail by itself).

As for the last option, there is a possibility that Google will reject the mail or put it to Spam folder. In case of rejection, there may be two reasons:

1. Google doesn't like the IP address of the machine you are sending mail from; considers it to be a spam source. You can do nothing about it - you have to stick to submission (ie. one of the previous methods).
2. Google sees that you are sending mail with your own Gmail address as "From:" but the mail is not coming from Google. Your machine is not Gmail, so it should not be sending mail in name of Gmail.

   The best option in that case is to have a properly registered own domain and use an email address from that domain as "From:" (the address doesn't need to actually work, ie. be able to receive mail; what is important is that the domain's **SPF record** designates the IP address of your machine as allowed to send mail in name of that domain). If you don't have your own domain, you have to experiment with made-up "From:" addresses (like eg. `someuser@localhost.localdomain`) to see if Google will accept them (maybe it can help to add these addresses as aliases on your Gmail account).

If Google accepts your mail, but puts it into Spam folder, remember to check it regularly and click "this is not spam" on each of your messages. Eventually Google may stop putting your mail to Spam. If it doesn't, create a filter rule on your Gmail account that tells it to "never send to Spam" for the sender address you use.

Although the last option seems from the description to be most complicated, it is actually the simplest one :), if Google will accept your mail. It only needs some experimenting to check if it will work.

Comment: Thank you, Raj, for your comprehensive answer. I did reconfigure Thunderbird for gmail successfully. I use sendmail via exim4 purely to alert myself of the results of backups and other scripts. At the very worst I can (and have) just changed the scripts to put the results in my logs directory, with the date as a suffix. It would still be nice to get sendmail to work. If I get 2FA to work, does that mean I will need to authorize the sending via my phone each time it runs? That would be a huge pain.

Comment: Here is a possible solution, which I will pursue. Stay posted. https://www.talk-about-it.ca/setting-up-exim4-with-gmail-and-2-factor-authentication/

Comment: That did not work. It did not appear to be any different from the original configuration I have done many times before. There does not appear to be any setting for OATH2 mentioned.

Comment: @user78290 No, you will have to use your phone only if you login to the web interface. Having 2FA enabled allows you to generate an application password on Google account, which you put into your exim configuration instead of your regular password, and it should work as previously. The article you linked mentions exactly that configuration.

Comment: I have tried to create a Protonmail account, only to find that the protonmail-bridge applies to paid users only. Since I am a retired software engineer I don't want that. I tried to configure mutt to do the job and failed - I must have got one of the many steps wrong. I ran dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config yet again.

Comment: I get the following in the exim mainlog:No server certificate defined; will use a selfsigned one.
 Suggested action: either install a certificate or change tls_advertise_hosts option

Comment: @user78290 Using self-signed certificates in mail servers is common; almost everybody does it and there's nothing wrong with that. I don't know what the option tls_advertise_hosts does in exim; you have to read the documentation.

Comment: lll of a sudden I have a flood of gmail messages generated by scripts appearing in my inbox. I had just changed the password in exim4.config to the application password! Hooray! Thanks for the help.

Comment: A better understanding of  "1. Google doesn't like the IP address of the machine you are sending mail from; considers it to be a spam source" is that Google may blacklist your entire ISP, not just the one IP address your machine.  Obviously, when your ISP uses DHCP for most of their customers, Google would blacklist entire blocks of IP addresses from the ISP, if they so desire.